# Websites explicitly designed for testing Web Scraping applications

Tags: r, unit-testing, testing, web-scraping

I'd like to test functionality that's based upon [`rvest`](https://github.com/hadley/rvest). Are there any websites that are explicitly designed for testing Web Scaping apps, i.e. websites whose structure does not change?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question is a bit off-topic really, but I'll answer anyway. I just googled for a few things, found this:

http://scraping.pro/web-scraper-test-drive/

which has its test pages here:

http://testing-ground.scraping.pro/

although I think this would make a nice project containing the test cases and the correct results in a form that could be used in any language's test framework...

I'm sure there's other things beyond the first google hit, which you should have done anyway.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I just did a really poor job phrasing what I was after in Google ;-) Thanks for answering anyway, though!

Comment: Websites unfortunately no longer available and that new answers are not acctepted is not acceptable.